# How do I mock a method call with arguments that don't implement `equals`?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing unit tests for a `SystemLoggingService` and mocking all calls to it's repository.
I'm using `Spring` with a `JPA` repository.

```
@Repository
public interface SystemLoggingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SystemLogEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SystemLogEntity> {
}
```

For a unit test of the service method `findAll(Searchable searchable,Pageable pageable)` I need to mock the repository method `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`

As one sees, the `Searchable` object gets transformed to a JPA `Specifications` object within the service logic.

The problem is that the JPA's `Specifications` class which my service logic will pass over to repository method does not implement `equals()`.

In other words, I cannot mock the repository method very precisely as I have to use `Matchers.any(Specifications.class)`

```
BDDMockito.given(systemLoggingRepository.findAll(Matchers.any(Specifications.class), Matchers.eq(pageRequest))).willReturn(...)
```

How bad is this for the quality of the unit test or is this common practice? What would be a different approach to this problem?
The `Specifications` object is a Spring framework class. It's not an option to just add the `equals()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer of @VolodymyrPasechnyk you might think of extracting the responsibility for creating the `Specifications` object to a separate class which would be another *dependency* to your CUT.

Comment: Yes this is an idea in mind. Currently I don't know how to test this creating procedure, but it's marked with an issue.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. If I do so, I also could use the class type matcher `Matchers.any(Specifications.class)` for mocking without any issues. Am I seeing this right?

Comment: @HerrDerb I agree. You can even configure the new dependency to return a mock of `Specifications` and verify this concrete object beeing passed along...

Comment: @HerrDerb there is no "wrong" or "right" as long as you code does what it is supposed to do, only "purposive" and "inappropriate"... ;o)

Answer (score 4):

You may try to capture Specifications with:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Specifications> specificationsCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Specifications.class);
BDDMockito.given(systemLoggingRepository.findAll(specificationsCaptor.capture(), Matchers.eq(pageRequest))).willReturn(...)
```

and then verify captured value:

```
Specifications capturedSpecifications = specificationsCaptor.getValue();
assertThat(capturedSpecifications.getSomeProperty(), ... )
```

You can find more info here: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15